# Semantic Wiki: Check form input if value already exists

Tags: mediawiki

we have a formular to create host names with some additional information.

Inside the formular we include a template, which gets the values via input fields:

```
{{{for template|IP|multiple|add button text=Add IP}}}
'''IP:''' {{{field|IP|mandatory|property=Host IP}}}

'''MAC:''' {{{field|MAC}}}
{{{end template}}}
```

We want to have a check if the given IP adress is already used by another host.

I already tried creating an array and iterating through the values and compare it with a given value: this works.

```
{{#arraydefine: myArray1 | {{ #ask: [[IP::+]] | mainlabel=- |headers=hide | ?IP }} }}
{{#arrayprint: myArray1||@@@@| {{#ifeq: @@@@ | {{{IP}}} | Duplicate @@@@ <br>| No duplicate @@@@ <br>}} }}
```

However, if I include this in the form itself, the IP input box doesn't assign the value to an actual variable {{{IP}}} - therefor I cannot access it with the method above.

I then tried to use it on the template "IP" directly. That works, but now it checks with every existing site which uses this template and of course, finds duplicates (because it checks it's own value against the array which also contains the value since it's already existing).

I spent almost 2 work days on this little issue now and I reach the limits of my understanding of semantic wiki. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since your page name is the host name, and host pages store the IP, you can do the following:

Ask for pages with the same IP as the current page :

```
{{#ask:[[IP::{{{IP}}}]] |mainlabel=-|?#-=}}
```

Store the result into an array, lets call it "hosts". The array now contains host names that have the same IP as the current page (with html link removed) and the current page itself.

Create a new array containing a single value, the current page name (using {{FULLPAGENAME}} magic word), lets call it "current"

Substract the two arrays :

```
{{#arraydiff:duplicate|hosts|current}}
```

Then check the length of the resulting array "duplicate".

if arraysize > 0, a host page different from current page exists with the same IP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
The pagename itself would be the hostname and the IP is just part of a table inside the page. Though, we can filter all created IP's through hosts. I'm not sure if I can apply your idea on our current construct then. I think my main problem is, that I don't know a way to access the given IP value inside the form, before saving.

Regarding the #ifexpr statement: couldn't I just use `#if | value | value is there | no value` and check if there is a value at all?

Comment: You are right, sorry. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it again, I think I wasn't able to explain my problem very good.
I found a way to compare two arrays and check for duplicates. The method itself is not my problem.
I want to check for duplicate IP, before the form is saved. I input a IP - click on preview -> then show a warning that there's a duplicate. The problem is, that the input field for the IP is inside another template and I wasn't able to extract that input.

If I try to do it inside the template, all existing pages will be checked and check against themselves which leads to all IP being a duplicate.

Comment: Are duplicates authorized or not ? You can specify "unique" constrain on a form field, but it won't let you save the page.